# Only inherit one time from a class

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I have a `class A` and I need a subclass of A `class B: public A`. How can I achieve that I can inherit from this class but nobody else ever can inherit again from this two classes?
If i make `class A` final B can't inherit from A.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want. You want B to be able to inherit from A, but no new classes to ever be able to inherit from either?

Comment: You might want to merge classes `A` and `B` into a single class, and declare that class `final`.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way in C++ to say that only one class can inherit from another class. Either a class is `final` (and thus uninheritable) or it isn't.

The absolute best you could do is have `A` declare its constructors private and make `B` a friend of `A`. But that would make it difficult for other users to create objects of type `A`.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented: I'm unclear on what you want. You want `B` to be able to inherit from `A`, but no new classes to ever be able to inherit from either? Going on that assumption your best bet is to make `A`'s ctor private and friend `B`, while making `B` final.

I don't know what you're after, design wise, but this is bad design. It does, however, answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea (though I don't think that's actually a good design):

```
class B;
class A {
     // everything's private
     friend class B; // << except for class B
};

class B final // << final prevents from further inheritance
: A {
     public:
     // What you want to publish ...
};
```

Though as mentioned before, I don't see that much point for `class A` unless you want to have more class instantiations like `class B`.